# showing imported data on progress bar

Tags: android, import, progress

I am working on Address book app in android.In my application i import contacts from phonebook in my app.while importing i am showing progress bar.I want to show the contacts being imported on the progressbar while importing.how to do this?
following is my code:-

```
public  class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        private  ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected Context applicationContext;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

            System.out.println("IN PreExecute");
            this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(applicationContext, "Importing Contacts", "Please Wait...", true);
             dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("IN BACKGROUND");
            addcontacts();//return flag1;
            //dialog.setMessage(name);
            return null ;


        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) 
        {
            System.out.println("IN update");

        }                      
        @Override                      
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {


            this.dialog.cancel();
            System.out.println("IN PostExecute");
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox1=new AlertDialog.Builder(Import.this);
            Cursor c=data.getData();
            int num=c.getCount();
            alertbox1.setMessage(+num+" contacts imported");
             c.close();
            // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
            alertbox1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                // do something when the button is clicked
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {

                    call();
                }
            });
            alertbox1.show();



        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onProgressUpdate` gets called every time we call `publishProgress` and the arguments from `publishProgress` go to `onProgressUpdate`

So in `doInBackground()` you can do

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

   for(int i=1; i<=totalContacts; ++i) {
        importNextContact();
        publishProgress(i/(float)totalContacts)*100);
   }

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions..but i want to show the contacts name being imported.

Answer (score 0):

Using dialog.setMessage("msg") is correct but remember that you can not change the ui in the 
doInBackground(...) method, so either you post a msg using an handler or you use runOnUiThread.

Comment: monika wants to show progress while contacts are being imported

Comment: I though she wanted to show the name of the contact that she is importing not the percentage imported so far. She says: "I want to show the contacts being imported on the progressbar while importing" and she has this line of code commented "//dialog.setMessage(name);"

Comment: It is possible to pass anything via publishProgress to the UI thread

Comment: Cool then, didn't pay enough attention to the signature.